# For every index, Find Largest element smaller that the current element to the right of the index in an unsorted array

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting, search, data-structures

I have an unsorted array. example: `arr = [5, 6, 7, 8, 4, 5, 6]`. My goal is to do the following:

```
for every index i:
   find j such that, 
     1. j > i and 
     2. arr[j] < arr[i] and 
     3. arr[j] is largest among all the numbers (smaller than arr[i]) between [i+1 till end].
     4. If there are multiple such j's, answer should be the lowest j.
     5. If no such element exists, return -1
```

***input***: [5, 6, 7, 8,  4,  5,  6]

***ouput***: [4, 5, 6, 6, -1, -1, -1]

***Brute Force*** `Time: O(N^2)`: We can run `2 loops`, basically for every index, traverse right and find the desired index if any.

***Using Balanced Binary Search Tree*** `Time: O(Nlog(N))`: We can build a balanced BST and for every node, compute the `inOrder predecessor.`

***Brute force*** is too expensive and ***Second approach*** is slightly complex. Can there be another approach using a `different data` structure like `Stack` or something to achieve our goal.

> NOTE: I could not find similar question on SO, if this is a duplicate
> question, please provide link to original one.

EDIT 1:
It was my bad to assume that implementation of both the approaches were very straightforward. So I am providing solution for the second approach.

***Using Balanced Binary Search Tree:***

```
class Node {
    left: Node;
    right: Node;
    val: number;
}

function addNodeToBBST(root: Node, val: numver): Node { // return newly added node
    ... any standard implementation AVL or RedBlack ...
}

function findNextLargestElement(arr: []) {
    const result = new Array<number>(arr.length);
    result[arr.length-1] = -1;
    const root = initializeTree(arr[0]);

    for(let i = arr.length - 2; i >= 0; i--) {
        const node = addNodeToBBST(arr[i], root); // O(Long(N))
        const pre = inOrderPredecessor(node, root); // O(Long(N))
        result[i] = pre && val.val || -1; 
    }

    return result;
}

function inOrderPredecessor(node: Node, root: Node) {
    if (root == null) {
         return;
    }
    if (root == node) {
        if (root.left != null) {
            let tmp = root.left;
            while (tmp.right)
                tmp = tmp.right;
            pre = tmp;
        }
        return pre;
    }

    if(root.val > node.val) {
        return inOrderPredecessor(root->left, node) ;
    } else {
        if(root->right && !root->right.left) {
            return root;
        }
        return inOrderPredecessor(root->right, node);
    }
}
```

Comment: _"Second approach is slightly complex"._ Have you tried implementing it?

Comment: I only see a problem statement but no attempt, code or concrete question.

Comment: I have added implementation of the second approach. Only reason i don't want to use it because of writing the logic of BBST.

Though I had already provided the gist of the solution, that I will only need to compute inOrder successor on each iteration, I think it was not that clear. 

Please check my updated question.